# Partial sums of $\sum_0^\infty z^n$

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

Let $z$ be a complex number with $|z|<1$. For every subset $A\subset\mathbb N$, the series $\sum_{m\in A}z^m$ is convergent. Denote $S(A)\in\mathbb{C}$ its sum and $\Sigma_z$ the set of all numbers $S(A)$. Remark that the cardinal of $\Sigma_z$ is (likely) that of ${\cal P}({\mathbb N})$, the continuum.

> Is it possible that $\Sigma_z$ be a neighbourhood of the origin ?

Comment: Clarification question: do you mean $\Sigma = \{\sum_{m\in A} z^m : |z|<1\}$ for fixed $A$? (So $\Sigma$ depends on $A$ and $S(A) = \sum_{m\in A} z^m$ depends on $z$? Or is it the other way around?)

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais: for fixed, non-trivial $A$ the function $z\mapsto \sum_{m\in A}z^m$ is a non-constant holomorphic function, thus open.

Comment: Aha! I think I had it the wrong way around: $z$ is fixed and $\Sigma = \{ S(A) : A \subseteq \mathbb{N}\}$. My confusion.

Comment: The question is: Does there exist $|z|<1$ such that $\Sigma_z=\{\sum\limits_{n\in A} z^n: A\subseteq \mathbb N_0\}$ is a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: I believe that for $z=re^{2\pi i\alpha}$ two necessary conditions are $r\ge 1/2$ and $\alpha\notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Why is $\alpha\notin\mathbb Q$ necessary when $r<1$?

Comment: To record what I just understood from @JochenWengenroth's comment: $r \geq 1/2$ is necessary because $\Sigma = z\Sigma \cup (1 + z\Sigma)$ and therefore $\mu(\Sigma) \leq 2r\mu(\Sigma)$ where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. ($\Sigma$ is evidently compact and therefore of finite measure.)

Comment: I agree with @EmilJeřábek. Wouldn't $z = i/\sqrt{2}$ work knowing that every integer has a negabinary representation? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Negabinary.html

Comment: You are right, @EmilJeřábek. That was too quick, and in view of Francois Dorais' answer indeed wrong.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth your intuition might still be correct in some way: perhaps $1 > r > 1/2$ is sufficient when $\alpha$ is irrational?

Comment: I think every $z$ with $|z|$ large enough (I mean, larger than some explicit number $<1$) works, by a Hausdorff dimension argument? at least showing $\Sigma_z$ has nonempty interior. A closely related problem has been quite studied, see https://lamington.wordpress.com/2014/12/21/roots-schottky-semigroups-and-bandts-conjecture/#more-2372. Btw $\Sigma_z$ is either a Cantor (automatic for $|z|<1/2$) or is compact connected, so is of cardinal $2^{\aleph_0}$ in all cases.

Comment: @YCor Not exactly, because $z$ must not be real !

Comment: @DenisSerre of course $z$ is not real in the linked blog.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais $\mu(z\Sigma) = r^2 \mu(\Sigma)$, right? So that gives $r \geq 1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @BartMichels Yes, absolutely! Thanks for correcting my tiredness! (I need to go to bed now.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The number $z = i/\sqrt2$ seems to work!

Given $x \in [-2/3,4/3]$ we can find a "negabinary" expansion
$$x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{b_k}{2^k},$$ where each $b_k \in \{0,1\}$.
Similarly, given $y \in [-2/3\sqrt2,4/3\sqrt2]$ we can find
$$y = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\frac{c_j}{2^j},$$
where each $c_j \in \{0,1\}$.
Therefore,
$x + iy = \sum_{n \in A} z^n$ where
$$A = \{2k : b_k = 1\} \cup \{2j+1 : c_j = 1 \}.$$

---

As explained in comment contributions by Bart Michels, Jochen Wegenroth and myself, $|z| \geq 1/\sqrt2$ is necessary. By definition, $$\Sigma_z = z\Sigma_z\cup(1+z\Sigma_z).$$ 
If $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure, then $\mu(z\Sigma_z) = |z|^2\mu(\Sigma_z)$ thus $\mu(\Sigma_z) \leq 2|z|^2\mu(\Sigma_z)$. Since $\Sigma_z$ is compact, it has finite measure and thus if $\mu(\Sigma_z)>0$ then we must have $|z|^2 \geq 1/2$.

It remains open whether $|z|\geq1/\sqrt2$ and $z \notin \mathbb{R}$ is sufficient for $\Sigma_z$ to contain $0$ in its interior.

Comment: I'm a bit tired so the interval bounds might be a bit off... Please check my arithmetic!

Comment: Denis: thank you for correcting my accidental abuse of the letter $i$. For what its worth, I think the case $z= i/\sqrt2$ is anecdotal and doesn't fully answer your question.

Comment: François, it answers my question. Of course, it raises the more general question of *which z has this property ?*. By the way, how do you prove that $\Sigma_z$ is measurable ?

Comment: Denis, $\Sigma_z$ is compact since it is a continuous image of $2^{\mathbb N}$. Therefore it is measurable and has finite measure.

Comment: See Davis, Chandler; Knuth, Donald E. Number representations and dragon curves-I. *J. Recreational Math.* 3 (1970), no. 2, 66–81.  and part II in *J. Recreational Math.* 3 (1970), no. 3, 133–149.